# I have a problem with the command \begin{landscape}, it generates a blank sheet

Tags: landscape

I have a problem with the command `\begin{landscape}`, it generates a blank sheet.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{longtable} % for 'longtable' environment
\usepackage{pdflscape} % for 'landscape' environment
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=2.2cm,right=2.2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}  % para el color de la primera fila de la tabla
\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\color{red}}  % sets colour of chapters
\sectionfont{\color{red}}  % sets colour of sections
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} % Eliminamos definiciones previas
\fancyhead[L]{Aseguramiento de la calidad}
\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[scale=0.09]{../../LOGO SOLO LA HOJA.PNG}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[C]{Aprendiz de soporte técnico}
\fancyfoot[L]{Recubrimientos especiales}
\setlength{\headheight}{13.6pt}
%---->%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}[H]{|p{5cm}|c|c|c|c|c|}
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{CRITERIOS DE ACEPTACIÓN}}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} }} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{CLIENTE TIPO A}}}& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{\textcolor{red} {CLIENTE TIPO B}}} \\ \cline{3-3} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Defectos}}}}                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Baker\\Hughes\\(LVOF)\end{tabular}}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Schlumberger\\(HVOF)\end{tabular}}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}NOV\\(HVOF)\end{tabular}}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Watherford\\(HVOF)\end{tabular}}}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \backslashbox[34mm]{\textbf{Fatiga}}{\textbf{Grieta}}}}&\multicolumn{4}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{No} son admisibles grietas y revestimiento fatigado a través de VT y MT \end{tabular}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Porosidades}}}& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{Son} admisibles 5 poros\\abiertos y 10 cerrados\\con $\varnothing\leq 1mm$ posterior\\ al primer tercio desde la\\ caja del rotor o stub a\\través de VT y MT \end{tabular}}&  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{No} son admisibles poros\\ abiertos y cerrados a tr-\\avé de VT \end{tabular}}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{No} son admisibles poros\\ abiertos y cerrados a tra-\\vés de VT y MT \end{tabular}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Pegas entre \\ revestimientos\end{tabular}}}}&  \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{No} Aplica \end{tabular}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Sellante}}}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{No} es admisible marcas de sellante a través de VT\\y \textbf{Son} admisibles con MT \end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{No} es admisible marcas de\\sellante a través de VT y\\ \textbf{Son} admisibles a través\\de MT con una $A^{2}<1in^{2}$\end{tabular}}\\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Marcas de\\ Pulido\end{tabular}}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{No} es admisible marcas\\de pulido en el revestimi-\\ento por medio de VT y\\MT\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{No} es admisibles marcas\\de pulido en el revestimi-\\ento por medio de VT y\\MT\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{No} es admisible marcas\\de pulido en el revestimi-\\ento por medio de VT y\\MT\end{tabular}}\\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Zonas sin\\ revestimiento\end{tabular}}}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textbf{No} es admisible zonas carentes de revestimiento \end{tabular}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Pulido \\ final\end{tabular}}}} &\multicolumn{4}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textbf{No} es admisible un componente con un mal acabado final y con los defectos\\mencionados anteriormente, este debe estar libre de cualquier discontinuidad \end{tabular}}\\ \hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textbf{No} es admisible un componente con defectos o discontinuidades en el revestimiento duro como:\\Arañazos, falta de adhesión, revestimiento no completamente fundido. Cualquier  discontinuidad\\en el revestimiento sera rechazado \end{tabular}} \\ \hline
\caption{Criterios de aceptación para el revestimiento duro - HVOF}
\label{tab:grupos}
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
\end{landscape}

\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Please reformat your code as code!  Mouse over the whole example to highlight it, then click the `{}` icon above the question box.

Comment: Please read our guides on [How to Ask Questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Minimal Working Examples (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) so we can help again in the future, you can format code as mentioned by @barbara so it takes up less space on the question

Comment: Never, ever, enclose a `longtable` environment inside a `center` environment.

Comment: longtable does not have an `[H]` option

Comment: Instead of `\begin{titlepage}\begin{landscape}...\end{landscape}\end{titlepage}`, do try `\begin{landscape}\begin{titlepage}...\end{titlepage}\end{landscape}`.

Comment: IMHO it makes not sense to put a table *with caption* into a `titlepage` environment. And putting a landscape table with caption into a `titlepage` environment even more doesn't make sense. So I would recommend to remove the `titlepage` *and* the `center` environment.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO it makes not sense to put a table with caption into a `titlepage` environment. And putting a landscape table with caption into a `titlepage` environment even more doesn't make sense. And putting a landscape table, that is allowed to span several pages, into a `titlepage` environment also does not make sense. So I would recommend to remove the `titlepage` and the center environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}  % para el color de la primera fila de la tabla
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{longtable} % for 'longtable' environment
\usepackage{pdflscape} % for 'landscape' environment
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=2.2cm,right=2.2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} % Eliminamos definiciones previas
\fancyhead[L]{Aseguramiento de la calidad}
\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[scale=0.09]{example-image}}% NOTE: image replaced to make a real MWE
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[C]{Aprendiz de soporte técnico}
\fancyfoot[L]{Recubrimientos especiales}
\setlength{\headheight}{13.6pt}
%---->%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}[H]{|p{5cm}|c|c|c|c|c|}
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{CRITERIOS DE ACEPTACIÓN}}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} }} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{CLIENTE TIPO A}}}& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{\textcolor{red} {CLIENTE TIPO B}}} \\ \cline{3-3} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Defectos}}}}                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Baker\\Hughes\\(LVOF)\end{tabular}}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Schlumberger\\(HVOF)\end{tabular}}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}NOV\\(HVOF)\end{tabular}}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Watherford\\(HVOF)\end{tabular}}}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \backslashbox[34mm]{\textbf{Fatiga}}{\textbf{Grieta}}}}&\multicolumn{4}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{No} son admisibles grietas y revestimiento fatigado a través de VT y MT \end{tabular}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Porosidades}}}& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{Son} admisibles 5 poros\\abiertos y 10 cerrados\\con $\varnothing\leq 1mm$ posterior\\ al primer tercio desde la\\ caja del rotor o stub a\\través de VT y MT \end{tabular}}&  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{No} son admisibles poros\\ abiertos y cerrados a tr-\\avé de VT \end{tabular}}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{No} son admisibles poros\\ abiertos y cerrados a tra-\\vés de VT y MT \end{tabular}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Pegas entre \\ revestimientos\end{tabular}}}}&  \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{No} Aplica \end{tabular}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Sellante}}}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{No} es admisible marcas de sellante a través de VT\\y \textbf{Son} admisibles con MT \end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{No} es admisible marcas de\\sellante a través de VT y\\ \textbf{Son} admisibles a través\\de MT con una $A^{2}<1in^{2}$\end{tabular}}\\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Marcas de\\ Pulido\end{tabular}}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{No} es admisible marcas\\de pulido en el revestimi-\\ento por medio de VT y\\MT\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{No} es admisibles marcas\\de pulido en el revestimi-\\ento por medio de VT y\\MT\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{No} es admisible marcas\\de pulido en el revestimi-\\ento por medio de VT y\\MT\end{tabular}}\\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Zonas sin\\ revestimiento\end{tabular}}}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textbf{No} es admisible zonas carentes de revestimiento \end{tabular}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Pulido \\ final\end{tabular}}}} &\multicolumn{4}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textbf{No} es admisible un componente con un mal acabado final y con los defectos\\mencionados anteriormente, este debe estar libre de cualquier discontinuidad \end{tabular}}\\ \hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textbf{No} es admisible un componente con defectos o discontinuidades en el revestimiento duro como:\\Arañazos, falta de adhesión, revestimiento no completamente fundido. Cualquier  discontinuidad\\en el revestimiento sera rechazado \end{tabular}} \\ \hline
\caption{Criterios de aceptación para el revestimiento duro - HVOF}
\label{tab:grupos}
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image: With page head and foot]

If you don't want page header and footer at the landscape page, don't use the `titlepage` environment (that, e.g., also resets the `page` counter), but use `\pagestyle` (or for one page `\thispagestyle`) inside the `landscape` environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}  % para el color de la primera fila de la tabla
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{longtable} % for 'longtable' environment
\usepackage{pdflscape} % for 'landscape' environment
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=2.2cm,right=2.2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} % Eliminamos definiciones previas
\fancyhead[L]{Aseguramiento de la calidad}
\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[scale=0.09]{example-image}}% NOTE: image replaced to make a real MWE
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[C]{Aprendiz de soporte técnico}
\fancyfoot[L]{Recubrimientos especiales}
\setlength{\headheight}{13.6pt}
%---->%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
  \pagestyle{empty}% or \thispagestyle{empty}, if only one page
\begin{longtable}[H]{|p{5cm}|c|c|c|c|c|}
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{CRITERIOS DE ACEPTACIÓN}}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} }} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{CLIENTE TIPO A}}}& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{\textcolor{red} {CLIENTE TIPO B}}} \\ \cline{3-3} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Defectos}}}}                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Baker\\Hughes\\(LVOF)\end{tabular}}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Schlumberger\\(HVOF)\end{tabular}}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}NOV\\(HVOF)\end{tabular}}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Watherford\\(HVOF)\end{tabular}}}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \backslashbox[34mm]{\textbf{Fatiga}}{\textbf{Grieta}}}}&\multicolumn{4}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{No} son admisibles grietas y revestimiento fatigado a través de VT y MT \end{tabular}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Porosidades}}}& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{Son} admisibles 5 poros\\abiertos y 10 cerrados\\con $\varnothing\leq 1mm$ posterior\\ al primer tercio desde la\\ caja del rotor o stub a\\través de VT y MT \end{tabular}}&  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{No} son admisibles poros\\ abiertos y cerrados a tr-\\avé de VT \end{tabular}}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{No} son admisibles poros\\ abiertos y cerrados a tra-\\vés de VT y MT \end{tabular}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Pegas entre \\ revestimientos\end{tabular}}}}&  \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{No} Aplica \end{tabular}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Sellante}}}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{No} es admisible marcas de sellante a través de VT\\y \textbf{Son} admisibles con MT \end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{No} es admisible marcas de\\sellante a través de VT y\\ \textbf{Son} admisibles a través\\de MT con una $A^{2}<1in^{2}$\end{tabular}}\\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Marcas de\\ Pulido\end{tabular}}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{No} es admisible marcas\\de pulido en el revestimi-\\ento por medio de VT y\\MT\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{No} es admisibles marcas\\de pulido en el revestimi-\\ento por medio de VT y\\MT\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{No} es admisible marcas\\de pulido en el revestimi-\\ento por medio de VT y\\MT\end{tabular}}\\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Zonas sin\\ revestimiento\end{tabular}}}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textbf{No} es admisible zonas carentes de revestimiento \end{tabular}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Pulido \\ final\end{tabular}}}} &\multicolumn{4}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textbf{No} es admisible un componente con un mal acabado final y con los defectos\\mencionados anteriormente, este debe estar libre de cualquier discontinuidad \end{tabular}}\\ \hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textbf{No} es admisible un componente con defectos o discontinuidades en el revestimiento duro como:\\Arañazos, falta de adhesión, revestimiento no completamente fundido. Cualquier  discontinuidad\\en el revestimiento sera rechazado \end{tabular}} \\ \hline
\caption{Criterios de aceptación para el revestimiento duro - HVOF}
\label{tab:grupos}
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image: without page head and foot]

Note: I've also removed all packages, which are not used in the example, and the second loading of packages.